# Load csv file with integers in Octave 3.2.4 under Windows

Tags: csv, load, octave

I am trying to import in Octave a file (i.e. data.txt) containing 2 columns of integers, such as:

```
101448,1077
96906,924
105704,1017
```

I use the following command:

```
data = load('data.txt')
```

However, the "data" matrix that results has a 1 x 1 dimension, with all the content of the data.txt file saved in just one cell. If I adjust the numbers to look like floats:

```
101448.0,1077.0
96906.0,924.0
105704.0,1017.0
```

the loading works as expected, and I obtain a matrix with 3 rows and 2 columns.

I looked at the various options that can be set for the load command but none of them seem to help. The data file has no headers, just plain integers, comma separated.

Any suggestions on how to load this type of data? How can I force Octave to cast the data as numeric?

Answer (score 1):

The `load` function is not to read csv files. It is meant to load files saved from Octave itself which define variables.

To read a csv file use `csvread ("data.txt")`. Also, 3.2.4 is a very old version no longer supported, you should upgrade.

Comment: After upgrading to 3.8.2, I used csvread() and that worked perfectly. Thank you for your help!